Stm32f407 usb audio microphone device descriptor request failed error
I'm trying to make a Usb microphone withf407 discovery board for my final project. I configured the descriptors they look fine but for some reason i get this
"Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)
A request for the USB device descriptor failed."
error message.
#ifndef USE_USBD_COMPOSITE
/* USB AUDIO device Configuration Descriptor */
__ALIGN_BEGIN static uint8_t USBD_AUDIO_CfgDesc[USB_AUDIO_CONFIG_DESC_SIZ] __ALIGN_END =
{
  /* Configuration 1 */
  0x09,                                 /* bLength */
  USB_DESC_TYPE_CONFIGURATION,          /* bDescriptorType */
  LOBYTE(USB_AUDIO_CONFIG_DESC_SIZ),    /* wTotalLength */
  HIBYTE(USB_AUDIO_CONFIG_DESC_SIZ),
  0x02,                                 /* bNumInterfaces */
  0x01,                                 /* bConfigurationValue */
  0x00,                                 /* iConfiguration */
#if (USBD_SELF_POWERED == 1U)
  0xC0,                                 /* bmAttributes: Bus Powered according to user configuration */
#else
  0x80,                                 /* bmAttributes: Bus Powered according to user configuration */
#endif /* USBD_SELF_POWERED */
  USBD_MAX_POWER,                       /* MaxPower (mA) */
  /* 09 byte*/

  /* USB Speaker Standard interface descriptor */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE,            /* bLength */
  USB_DESC_TYPE_INTERFACE,              /* bDescriptorType */
  0x00,                                 /* bInterfaceNumber */
  0x00,                                 /* bAlternateSetting */
  0x00,                                 /* bNumEndpoints */
  USB_DEVICE_CLASS_AUDIO,               /* bInterfaceClass */
  AUDIO_SUBCLASS_AUDIOCONTROL,          /* bInterfaceSubClass */
  AUDIO_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED,             /* bInterfaceProtocol */
  0x00,                                 /* iInterface */
  /* 09 byte*/

  /* USB Speaker Class-specific AC Interface Descriptor */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE,            /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_CONTROL_HEADER,                 /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  0x00,          /* 1.00 */             /* bcdADC */
  0x01,
  0x27,                                 /* wTotalLength */
  0x00,
  0x01,                                 /* bInCollection */
  0x01,                                 /* baInterfaceNr */
  /* 09 byte*/

  /* USB Speaker Input Terminal Descriptor */
  AUDIO_INPUT_TERMINAL_DESC_SIZE,       /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_CONTROL_INPUT_TERMINAL,         /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  0x01,                                 /* bTerminalID */
  0x01,                                 /* wTerminalType AUDIO_TERMINAL_USB_STREAMING   0x0101 */
  0x02,
  0x00,                                 /* bAssocTerminal */
  0x01,                                 /* bNrChannels */
  0x00,                                 /* wChannelConfig 0x0000  Mono */
  0x00,
  0x00,                                 /* iChannelNames */
  0x00,                                 /* iTerminal */
  /* 12 byte*/

  /* USB Speaker Audio Feature Unit Descriptor */
  0x09,                                 /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_CONTROL_FEATURE_UNIT,           /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  AUDIO_OUT_STREAMING_CTRL,             /* bUnitID */
  0x01,                                 /* bSourceID */
  0x01,                                 /* bControlSize */
  AUDIO_CONTROL_MUTE,                   /* bmaControls(0) */
  0,                                    /* bmaControls(1) */
  0x00,                                 /* iTerminal */
  /* 09 byte */

  /* USB Speaker Output Terminal Descriptor */
  0x09,      /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_CONTROL_OUTPUT_TERMINAL,        /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  0x03,                                 /* bTerminalID */
  0x01,                                 /* wTerminalType  0x0301 */
  0x01,
  0x00,                                 /* bAssocTerminal */
  0x02,                                 /* bSourceID */
  0x00,                                 /* iTerminal */
  /* 09 byte */

  /* USB Speaker Standard AS Interface Descriptor - Audio Streaming Zero Bandwidth */
  /* Interface 1, Alternate Setting 0                                              */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE,            /* bLength */
  USB_DESC_TYPE_INTERFACE,              /* bDescriptorType */
  0x01,                                 /* bInterfaceNumber */
  0x00,                                 /* bAlternateSetting */
  0x00,                                 /* bNumEndpoints */
  USB_DEVICE_CLASS_AUDIO,               /* bInterfaceClass */
  AUDIO_SUBCLASS_AUDIOSTREAMING,        /* bInterfaceSubClass */
  AUDIO_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED,             /* bInterfaceProtocol */
  0x00,                                 /* iInterface */
  /* 09 byte*/

  /* USB Speaker Standard AS Interface Descriptor - Audio Streaming Operational */
  /* Interface 1, Alternate Setting 1                                           */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE,            /* bLength */
  USB_DESC_TYPE_INTERFACE,              /* bDescriptorType */
  0x01,                                 /* bInterfaceNumber */
  0x01,                                 /* bAlternateSetting */
  0x01,                                 /* bNumEndpoints */
  USB_DEVICE_CLASS_AUDIO,               /* bInterfaceClass */
  AUDIO_SUBCLASS_AUDIOSTREAMING,        /* bInterfaceSubClass */
  AUDIO_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED,             /* bInterfaceProtocol */
  0x00,                                 /* iInterface */
  /* 09 byte*/

  /* USB Speaker Audio Streaming Interface Descriptor */
  AUDIO_STREAMING_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE,  /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_STREAMING_GENERAL,              /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  0x03,                                 /* bTerminalLink */
  0x01,                                 /* bDelay */
  0x01,                                 /* wFormatTag AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM  0x0001 */
  0x00,
  /* 07 byte*/

  /* USB Speaker Audio Type III Format Interface Descriptor */
  0x0B,                                 /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_STREAMING_FORMAT_TYPE,          /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  AUDIO_FORMAT_TYPE_I,                  /* bFormatType */
  0x01,                                 /* bNrChannels */
  0x02,                                 /* bSubFrameSize :  2 Bytes per frame (16bits) */
  16,                                   /* bBitResolution (16-bits per sample) */
  0x01,                                 /* bSamFreqType only one frequency supported */
  AUDIO_SAMPLE_FREQ(USBD_AUDIO_FREQ),   /* Audio sampling frequency coded on 3 bytes */
  /* 11 byte*/

  /* Endpoint 1 - Standard Descriptor */
  AUDIO_STANDARD_ENDPOINT_DESC_SIZE,    /* bLength */
  USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT,               /* bDescriptorType */
  0x81,                         /* bEndpointAddress 1 out endpoint */
  USBD_EP_TYPE_ISOC,                    /* bmAttributes */
  AUDIO_PACKET_SZE(USBD_AUDIO_FREQ),    /* wMaxPacketSize in Bytes (Freq(Samples)*2(Stereo)*2(HalfWord)) */
  AUDIO_FS_BINTERVAL,                   /* bInterval */
  0x00,                                 /* bRefresh */
  0x00,                                 /* bSynchAddress */
  /* 09 byte*/

  /* Endpoint - Audio Streaming Descriptor */
  AUDIO_STREAMING_ENDPOINT_DESC_SIZE,   /* bLength */
  AUDIO_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,       /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_ENDPOINT_GENERAL,               /* bDescriptor */
  0x00,                                 /* bmAttributes */
  0x00,                                 /* bLockDelayUnits */
  0x00,                                 /* wLockDelay */
  0x00,
  /* 07 byte*/
} ;

/* USB Standard Device Descriptor */
__ALIGN_BEGIN static uint8_t USBD_AUDIO_DeviceQualifierDesc[USB_LEN_DEV_QUALIFIER_DESC] __ALIGN_END =
{
  USB_LEN_DEV_QUALIFIER_DESC,
  USB_DESC_TYPE_DEVICE_QUALIFIER,
  0x00,
  0x02,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x40,
  0x01,
  0x00,
};
#endif /* USE_USBD_COMPOSITE  */

static uint8_t AUDIOOutEpAdd = AUDIO_OUT_EP;
/**
  * @}
  */

/** @defgroup USBD_AUDIO_Private_Functions
  * @{
  */

/**
  * @brief  USBD_AUDIO_Init
  *         Initialize the AUDIO interface
  * @param  pdev: device instance
  * @param  cfgidx: Configuration index
  * @retval status
  */
static uint8_t USBD_AUDIO_Init(USBD_HandleTypeDef *pdev, uint8_t cfgidx)
{
  UNUSED(cfgidx);
  USBD_AUDIO_HandleTypeDef *haudio;

  /* Allocate Audio structure */
  haudio = (USBD_AUDIO_HandleTypeDef *)USBD_malloc(sizeof(USBD_AUDIO_HandleTypeDef));

  if (haudio == NULL)
  {
    pdev->pClassDataCmsit[pdev->classId] = NULL;
    return (uint8_t)USBD_EMEM;
  }

  pdev->pClassDataCmsit[pdev->classId] = (void *)haudio;
  pdev->pClassData = pdev->pClassDataCmsit[pdev->classId];

#ifdef USE_USBD_COMPOSITE
  /* Get the Endpoints addresses allocated for this class instance */
  AUDIOOutEpAdd = USBD_CoreGetEPAdd(pdev, USBD_EP_OUT, USBD_EP_TYPE_ISOC, (uint8_t)pdev->classId);
#endif /* USE_USBD_COMPOSITE */

  if (pdev->dev_speed == USBD_SPEED_HIGH)
  {
    pdev->ep_out[AUDIOOutEpAdd & 0xFU].bInterval = AUDIO_HS_BINTERVAL;
  }
  else   /* LOW and FULL-speed endpoints */
  {
    pdev->ep_out[AUDIOOutEpAdd & 0xFU].bInterval = AUDIO_FS_BINTERVAL;
  }

  /* Open EP OUT */
  (void)USBD_LL_OpenEP(pdev, AUDIOOutEpAdd, USBD_EP_TYPE_ISOC, AUDIO_OUT_PACKET);
  pdev->ep_out[AUDIOOutEpAdd & 0xFU].is_used = 1U;

  haudio->alt_setting = 0U;
  haudio->offset = AUDIO_OFFSET_UNKNOWN;
  haudio->wr_ptr = 0U;
  haudio->rd_ptr = 0U;
  haudio->rd_enable = 0U;

  /* Initialize the Audio output Hardware layer */
  if (((USBD_AUDIO_ItfTypeDef *)pdev->pUserData[pdev->classId])->Init(USBD_AUDIO_FREQ,
                                                                      AUDIO_DEFAULT_VOLUME,
                                                                      0U) != 0U)
  {
    return (uint8_t)USBD_FAIL;
  }

  /* Prepare Out endpoint to receive 1st packet */
  (void)USBD_LL_PrepareReceive(pdev, AUDIOOutEpAdd, haudio->buffer,
                               AUDIO_OUT_PACKET);

  return (uint8_t)USBD_OK;
}

/**
  * @brief  USBD_AUDIO_Init
  *         DeInitialize the AUDIO layer
  * @param  pdev: device instance
  * @param  cfgidx: Configuration index
  * @retval status
  */
static uint8_t USBD_AUDIO_DeInit(USBD_HandleTypeDef *pdev, uint8_t cfgidx)
{
  UNUSED(cfgidx);

#ifdef USE_USBD_COMPOSITE
  /* Get the Endpoints addresses allocated for this class instance */
  AUDIOOutEpAdd = USBD_CoreGetEPAdd(pdev, USBD_EP_OUT, USBD_EP_TYPE_ISOC, (uint8_t)pdev->classId);
#endif /* USE_USBD_COMPOSITE */

  /* Open EP OUT */
  (void)USBD_LL_CloseEP(pdev, AUDIOOutEpAdd);
  pdev->ep_out[AUDIOOutEpAdd & 0xFU].is_used = 0U;
  pdev->ep_out[AUDIOOutEpAdd & 0xFU].bInterval = 0U;

  /* DeInit  physical Interface components */
  if (pdev->pClassDataCmsit[pdev->classId] != NULL)
  {
    ((USBD_AUDIO_ItfTypeDef *)pdev->pUserData[pdev->classId])->DeInit(0U);
    (void)USBD_free(pdev->pClassDataCmsit[pdev->classId]);
    pdev->pClassDataCmsit[pdev->classId] = NULL;
    pdev->pClassData = NULL;
  }

  return (uint8_t)USBD_OK;
}

I looked into the code and i think its because of the #ifdef directive in the USBD_AUDIO_Initfunction but i am not sure this is my first time dealing with usb.
I tried this project's descriptors, asked ChatGPT and tried it's answers, looked into the original usb device class definition for audio devices document and tried that too but none of it worked, same error over and over again.
